# MediaPlayer not preparing

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I had code that was working perfectly then I wrote another class in my project, went back to try the exact same code and started getting an error.

This is my code:

```
public class myMediaPlayer extends Activity implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener{

private TextureView mTextureView;
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_channel_player);

    mTextureView = (TextureView)findViewById(R.id.Video);
    mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
    Log.d("debug","Listener Set");

}


@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
    Surface s = new Surface(surface);
    Log.d("debug", "Surface Texture Available");
    try {
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.t));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("IOException", "setDataSource method faulty");
        }
        Log.d("debug", "data source set");
        mMediaPlayer.setSurface(s);
        Log.d("debug", "Surface set");
        try {
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("IOException", "Prepare method problem");
        }
        Log.d("debug", "prepared");
        mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
        Log.d("debug", "listeners set");
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("error", e.getMessage());
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("error", e.getMessage());
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("error", e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
    //TODO
    Log.d("Debug","SurfaceTextureSizeChanged");
}

@Override
public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
    Log.d("Debug","SurfaceTextureDestroyed");
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
    //TODO
    Log.d("Debug","SurfaceTextureUpdated");
}

@Override
public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
    Log.d("Debug","BufferingUpdate");
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.d("Debug", "Media Player Complete");
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.d("Debug","Media Player Prepared");
    mp.start();
}

@Override
public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
    Log.d("Debug","VideoSizeChanged");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d("Debug","Activity Destroyed");
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) mMediaPlayer.release();
}
```

}

This is pretty much exactly the same as the demos do it. It was working for a while, but suddenly there is an error with the prepare method (I get "prepare method error" in my log). Anyone have any idea why it suddenly stopped working?

This is the LogCat output:

> 01-12 20:18:10.530  23003-23003/com.edifyelectronics.tv.app
>   W/ActivityThread﹕ Application com.edifyelectronics.tv.app can be
>   debugged on port 8100... 01-12 20:18:10.559 
>   23003-23003/com.edifyelectronics.tv.app D/debug﹕ Listener Set 01-12
>   20:18:10.570  23003-23023/com.edifyelectronics.tv.app
>   D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true 01-12
>   20:18:10.579  23003-23003/com.edifyelectronics.tv.app D/Atlas﹕
>   Validating map... 01-12 20:18:10.608 
>   23003-23023/com.edifyelectronics.tv.app I/Adreno-EGL﹕
>   : QUALCOMM Build: 10/28/14, c33033c,
>   Ia6306ec328 01-12 20:18:10.609 
>   23003-23023/com.edifyelectronics.tv.app I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized
>   EGL, version 1.4 01-12 20:18:10.637 
>   23003-23023/com.edifyelectronics.tv.app D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling
>   debug mode 0 01-12 20:18:10.742 
>   23003-23003/com.edifyelectronics.tv.app D/debug﹕ Surface Texture
>   Available 01-12 20:18:11.080  23003-23003/com.edifyelectronics.tv.app
>   D/debug﹕ data source set 01-12 20:18:11.082 
>   23003-23003/com.edifyelectronics.tv.app D/debug﹕ Surface set 01-12
>   20:18:11.176  23003-23021/com.edifyelectronics.tv.app E/MediaPlayer﹕
>   error (1, -2147483648) 01-12 20:18:11.177 
>   23003-23003/com.edifyelectronics.tv.app D/IOException﹕ Prepare method
>   problem 01-12 20:18:11.177  23003-23003/com.edifyelectronics.tv.app
>   D/debug﹕ prepared 01-12 20:18:11.177 
>   23003-23003/com.edifyelectronics.tv.app D/debug﹕ listeners set

Comment: what kind of error u r getting ?

Comment: it will be better to see the logcat output..

Comment: I get the non-specific error. Logcat output added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer or solution, but without doing anything, it just suddenly started working again.